# Matlab Link data for a line graph on a scatter plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a line which is plotted on another scatter plot. This line changes its shape from time to time. Is there any way by which I can specify in my program that the data for drawing this line is dynamic so that the plot updates by itself when the data changes?

Now what I am doing is draw the entire figure again after each data update. The program has very large number of iterations(>5000) and I need to visualize every change. That means figure should be drawn 5000 times. This is making my program very slow. Is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The [refreshdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refreshdata.html) function might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically update a graph when a source variable changes, use the [`linkdata` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html). MathWorks has a is a [great introduction page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/making-graphs-responsive-with-data-linking.html). However, there is a short example in the documentation:

```
x = [1:20];
y = rand(20,3);
area(x,y)
linkdata on
```

Then you can change a variable and the plot automatically redraws:

```
y(10,:) = 0;
```

Automatic update.

Note: Changing the source to a different variable entirely is a different thing.  If `YDataSource` is reassigned, then [`refreshdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refreshdata.html) would be needed, as pointed out by Molly. Otherwise, this will keep your plot up-to-date when the variable changes.

One caveat is described on [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html?searchHighlight=linkdata#br65rof):

> `linkdata` buffers updates to data and dispatches them to plots at roughly half-second intervals. This makes data linking not suitable for smoothly animating changes in data values unless they are updated in loops that are forced to execute two times per second or less.

Comment: I tried this. and added drawing of figure in the first iteration. But the figure does not get updated. Logic for drawing figure is in another matlab file. Does this make any difference? Do I have to specify anything else?

Comment: @Doubting Can you clarify on how you are drawing the figure and what code is in each file? I think you need to make the plot with a certain variable, and then just update that variable, not plot a new variable. NOTE: I think the `linkdata on` command needs to be performed in the _same workspace_ containing the variables being updated.

Comment: @Doubting Have a look [at this section of this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html?searchHighlight=linkdata#br65rof). You may need a very short delay, like `pause(0.1)` or perhaps a `drawnow` if your iterations are too fast.